# Restore over dns alias fails with Operating system error 1326(The user name or password is incorrect.)

Tags: sql-server, spn

following configuration:

- SQL Server is running on server.domain.intra with an gMSA.
- DNS alias: server-db-dev.domain.intra
- gMSA Permissions on backup share: Full Control
- SPNs set for gMSA:

  - MSSQLSvc/server.domain.intra:1433
  - MSSQLSvc/server.domain.intra
  - MSSQLSvc/server-dev-db1.domain.intra:1433
  - MSSQLSvc/server-dev-db1:1433

Problem:
When the restore is started with \server.domain.intra\BackupShare$, the restore finish successfully but with the DNS alias we get the error "Operating system error 1326(The user name or password is incorrect.)"

I have the feeling that the gMSA should be configured to allow to be delegated to the dns alias.
Or do you have any other ideas how to solve the problem?

Thank you very much and kind regards,
Olaf

Comment: You are missing that SPN `setspn server.domain.intra -s HOST/server-db-dev.domain.intra`

Comment: @Charlieface - That was the one missing. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow Kerberos Authentication on the network share, you need to add the SPN for the alias with the `HOST` service (it's actually a group of services), as otherwise the server is not able to create a Kerberos ticket for it.

The server itself does not realize that it is connecting to a loopback, so even if it's on the same server it needs the SPN.

```
setspn server.domain.intra -s HOST/server-db-dev.domain.intra
```